# angular scope.$watch not working in directive. Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive called tabset

```
angular.module('widgets')
.directive('tabset', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controllerAs: 'tabs',
        bindToController: {
            tabInfo: '=tabdata'
        },
        templateUrl: 'Template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabs) {
            //var tabs = this;
            scope.$watch('tabs.tabInfo', function() {
                tabs.populateDataProvider();
                console.log('this just kicked');
            }, true);
        },
        controller: ['$filter', '$state', function($filter, $state) {
            this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex < 0 ? 0 : this.activeIndex;
            this.selectTab = function selectTab(tab) {
                $state.go(tab.state);
            };
        }]
    };
});
```

I now have a dependent directive called checkTab which requires "tabset" and on change to tabset.tabInfo, teh watch needs to kick in and populatedataprovider needs to be triggered. However that does not seem to be teh case.

Here is the checkTab directive,

```
 angular.module('widgets')
.directive('checkTab', ['XXXService',
 function(XXXService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'tabset',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            var tabCtrl = ctrls;
            tabCtrl.tabInfo.push({
                name: 'newtab',
                state: 'newtab'
            });

            **var selectFn = tabCtrl.populateDataProvider;**

            tabCtrl.populateDataProvider = function() {
                selectFn.apply(tabCtrl, arguments);
                (function recurse(dataObj) {
                    for (var key in dataObj) {

                        var obj = dataObj[key];

                        if (obj.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
                                recurse(obj.children[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })(tabCtrl.dataprovider);
            };
        }
    };
  }
 ]);
```

However ,  when the new tab is added to tabset.tabInfo.  I get an error **Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined** where teh selectFn is undefined.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do but have you tried var selectFn = angular.copy(tabCtrl.populateDataProvider);  ?

Comment: no luck there, nothing changed.  I essentially want to pass the  tabs.tabInfo as the argument when the watch kicks in and selectFn should  be able to be executed  by applying the arguments

Comment: Seems like tabCtrl.populateDataProvider is undefined, your parent scope (tabset controller) doesn't define it, it may be the issue. Or does 'tabdata' define it ?